# Cassandra: how move a database from one server to another quickly?

Tags: cassandra, backup, cassandra-2.0

It's a backup restore question. We have a single node running Cassandra. We have also rsync'ed the /var/lib/cassandra folder into another (backup) server.

In case of emergency, we can quickly boot a new server and transfer files there. But the question is: will it work then? Let's assume we have the same Cassandra versions on both old and the new server, and the same OS version. **Is it enough to simply transfer the whole /var/lib/cassandra folder**? As you understand, backups is a critical thing so I want to be sure everything will be ok.

(we currently are using dsc2.0 package from the Ubuntu's repos)

Yes, running a 'normal' cluster with 2-3 nodes would be a better choice, I know. Both performance and reliability would increase. But for now we have what we have - it's a single node. And for some reasons  right now we will not switch to a multinode cluster.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to define what you mean, exactly, by "will it work?"  Depending on your specific configuration (which is not clear) and how your rsync is set up (not specified) there is a high probability that Cassandra will be able to start up on your backup node, assuming your rsync includes *both* the commitlog and SSTables for all relevant keyspaces/CFs.  (Have you tested this yet?)  But starting up is not necessarily the same as "working", so please clarify.

Comment: @WilliamPrice I meant 'start and work properly'. Any backup is made for saving the data, so I'd like to backup the data and restore it back, so if I have, say, 1 million records in 3 tables, after restoring I should see these 1 million records in these 3 tables exactly as it was before.

Comment: @WilliamPrice, I'm rsync'ing the whole /var/lib/cassandra folder, with the default config. Please correct me if I'm wrong but the default config means storing both sstables as well as commitlogs there. As I have a single HDD, then both sstables and commitlogs should be backed up.

Comment: In theory, yes, your approach should work -- but the data will only be as recent as both the (1) most recent flush of the commit log(s) which can be configuration-dependent in Cassandra, and (2) how frequently your rsync runs and succeeds.  If you're regularly writing to Cassandra, you will still have the potential for some loss of recently-written data even if it starts up properly.

Comment: The potential of data loss is present with all cold/offline backup solutions. Replicating the node would provide better results, but I understand that's not an option.